# Display loader in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am just submitting one form.Its taking some time to return the response,on that time I need to show the loader.
This is my code

```
<div id="page-loading">
            <img style="display:none; margin:0 auto;"  src="~/images/loader.gif" />
        </div>
```

Script:

```
$scope.myFunc = function (leave) {
                            $scope.leaveDetails=leave;
                            console.log($scope.leaveDetails)
                            var requestHeaders = {
                                "content-type": 'application/json'
                            }
                            var httpRequest = {
                                method: 'POST',
                                url: '/Admin/sendRequest',
                                headers: requestHeaders,
                                data: $scope.leaveDetails
                            }
                            $http(httpRequest).then(function (response) {
                                $timeout(function () {
                                   $('#page-loading').fadeOut('slow');
                                }, 1000);

                                alert("successfully applied")
                                window.location= "/admin/Home";
                            })
                        }
```

But its not displaying the loader But taking more time to return the response.
If I give `display:block` here, `<img style="display:none; margin:0 auto;"  src="~/images/loader.gif" />` by default loader is coming but I need to show it only `on submit` of form.
Any suggestion?

Comment: You can use scope variable to show and hide image using ng-if or ng-show.

Comment: Please use angular in your angular application, not that jquery DOM stuff. It will save you a lot of trouble like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a variable to scope like `$scope.loading = true` at the top of your method, and then in `finally` handler of http promise set it to `false`.

```
$http(httpRequest).then(...).finally(function() { $scope.loading = false; })
```

Based on that flag you can hide and show your loader.

```
<div id="page-loading" ng-if="loading">
    <img style="margin:0 auto;"  src="~/images/loader.gif" />
</div>
```

Comment: why do I use `.finally`

Comment: In case if your request fails, you will want to hide the loader as well, won't you?

Comment: As soon as you redirect somewhere else, `$timeout` is extraneous there.

Comment: Create a plunker, and tell what's wrong with it, and we'll try to help you fix it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147346/discussion-between-xreeqz-and-user7397787).

Answer (score 2):

I would use ng-if to show and hide the loader:

```
<div ng-if="loaderVisible">
     <img margin:0 auto;"  src="~/images/loader.gif" />
</div>
```

Then you can make loaderVisible = true in the beginning of your function and hide it again by making it false during the callback success.

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular-busy below is link,

https://github.com/cgross/angular-busy

It's very simple to use no need of this all and if loader you not like then you can change loader CSS als